# Angular Navigate to "/unauthorised" route but keep the URL the same

Tags: angular

I have a guard that navigates to a "/unauthorised" route when the user doesn't have permission to access the current page (can be any page).

```js
@Injectable()
export class PermissionGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private readonly permissionService: PermissionService, private readonly router: Router) {}

  async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    const hasPermission = await this.permissionService.userHasPermissionForRoute(state.url);

    if (!hasPermission) {
      await this.router.navigate(['/unauthorised']); // still need to show the state.url in the browser
    }

    return hasPermission;
  }
}
```

However, I've had a request for the URL to stay the same.

Ie. If they access `/my-page` and they don't have permission they are navigated the `/unauthorised` page but the URL in the browser remains `/my-page`.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

I had thought that using `this.router.navigate('/unauthorised', {replaceUrl: false})` would work, but doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `{ skipLocationChange: true }`. According to the documentation:

```
// When true, navigates without pushing a new state into history.

// Navigate silently to /view
this.router.navigate(['/view'], { skipLocationChange: true });
```

You'll be able to route to `/unauthorised` without the URL changing.

Comment: To add to this, here is the [documentation of the skipLocationChange](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationBehaviorOptions#skipLocationChange).